# Why does the error "psycopg.transaction.OutOfOrderTransactionNesting" happens? and how to avoid it?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg3

I'm running a telegram bot using python-telegram-bot==13.13 and psycopg==3.1.4 for database connections.
Yesterday this error raised suddenly:
`psycopg.transaction.OutOfOrderTransactionNesting: transaction commit at the wrong nesting level`.

The function is more than a hundred of lines so I'll put only the transaction where the error raised:

Due to the traceback, it happened on the first line here:

```
with conn.transaction():
    cur.execute(f'update testauth_profile set balance=balance-{price} where telegram_id={update.effective_chat.id}')
    cur.execute(f'update testauth_profile set balance=balance+{price-cost} where id=622')
    cur.execute(f"insert into testauth_log values ('{data['mdn']}','{name}',now(),{context.user_data['uid']},'{data['id']}')")
    cur.execute(f"insert into verifications values ('{data['id']}',now()+interval'15 minute',{update.effective_chat.id},0,'{data['mdn']}',{price-cost},{price},{context.user_data['lang']})")
```

where `conn` is a psycopg connection and has autocommit=True. and `cur` is a cursor from `conn`.

After that, everything happend on the database in the next 11 hours were rolled back and I lost them permanently.

Any idea for what caused this error? and how can I avoid this in the future?

I searched in google but nothing about this error.
I had a look at the postgres logs in /var/logs/postgres/ but there was no errors in the whole 11 hours and even before.
The strange thing is that I never touched the code and it has been running for days without any problem.
The function where the error was raised, was executed many times before without problems.

Comment: To state the obvious, this error happened because of a bug, either in the bot code (more likely) or in the psycopg code (less likely). Like for a car engine failing to start, there could be lots of different reasons for this behaviour, and more data (logs, stack traces) is needed to identify the real problem.

Comment: 1) Show the actual complete code in your question. 2) Having a transaction open for 11 hours is a bad idea period.

Comment: Thanks for comments.. I edited the question to add the code snippet.
I never open a transaction for 11 hours, I put  my multi-line transactions in a `with conn.transaction():` to make sure closing them

Comment: I've encountered the same issue with psycopg3 and lost my data for last 20 hours. Any update on this one by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

All I did for now is combine all consecutive updates and inserts into one query where possible.

For example, I converted the code in my question to:

```
cur.execute(f'''update testauth_profile set balance=balance-{price} where telegram_id={update.effective_chat.id};
update testauth_profile set balance=balance+{price-cost} where id=622';
insert into testauth_log values ('{data['mdn']}','{name}',now(),{context.user_data['uid']},'{data['id']}');
insert into verifications values ('{data['id']}',now()+interval'15 minute',{update.effective_chat.id},0,'{data['mdn']}',{price-cost},{price},{context.user_data['lang']});''')
```

In addition to that, I created a new cursor in every callback in the code (the cursor is deleted at the end of the callback).
I don't know if this is the solution, but I didn't face the problem again.